# Use of LENGTH in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

What is the use of LENGTH in SQL. You may answer with reference to following CTE Query

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
AS
(
SELECT STATEMENT = CAST('I Like ' AS VARCHAR(300)), LEN('I Like ') 
UNION ALL
SELECT
      CAST(STATEMENT + 'Stackoverflow! ' AS VARCHAR(300))
      , LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
WHERE LENGTH < 300
)
SELECT STATEMENT, LENGTH FROM ShowMessage
```

Comment: Statement and Length as just placeholder column names in your query. Is there something more you were trying to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH ShowMessage(STATEMENT, LENGTH)
```

In this part of query you assigned the first and second column names.
Length is just an alias.

It is similar to :

```
WITH ShowMessage
AS
(
SELECT STATEMENT = CAST('I Like ' AS VARCHAR(300)) as 'STATEMENT', LEN('I Like ') as 'Length'
UNION ALL
SELECT
      CAST(STATEMENT + 'Stackoverflow! ' AS VARCHAR(300))
      , LEN(STATEMENT) FROM ShowMessage
WHERE LENGTH < 300
)
SELECT STATEMENT, LENGTH FROM ShowMessage
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the above functionality, because i want to achieve someting similar. How does it works iteratively.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma The first part is called the Anchor member, the part after the `UNION ALL` is the recursive member, referencing the CTE itself. For more info you could start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 "styles" of declaring a CTE - in respect of column naming/aliasing. As far as I am aware, the differences are strictly cosmetic;

```
------------------
--  Style 1
--  Alias inside
------------------
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT   FirstName  = fn
            ,LastName   = sn
    FROM MyTable
)
...
------------------
--  Style 2
--  Alias outside
------------------
;WITH MyCTE (FirstName, LastName) AS
(
    SELECT   fn
            ,sn
    FROM MyTable
)
...
```

Comment: I came to know that after seeing @Amirrezza's answer